# I'm looking for a straight forward tutorial on setting up a remote access VPN, preferably free

Tags: vpn

I want to connect me and 3 friends networks together so we can work together on visual studio projects together using the Team Foundation Server. From what I've read the easiest and best way to do this is to setup a VPN. I was wondering if someone couldn't point me in the right direction.

I was hoping to get a free solution and I'm aware that might not be possible. Obviously it would have to be Windows compatible. I was looking at OpenVPN but it sounds like it's geared towards linux and I don't know if the Team Foundation Server would work with it.

Also it would always be the same 4 networks connected. So I don't need remote access from other IPs. But as we don't have static IPs from our ISPs I'd need the ability to go in and change it every few months when my ISP swaps my IP.

Comment: +1 because doesn't make sense why people have negative valued your quesiton!

Comment: I think the -1 was because the question seems poorly researched prior to asking it here, mainly the "openvpn geared towards linux" thing.

Comment: Well, in my defense if you go to OpenVPN's software packages on their site they list only linux distributions. I wasn't sure if the server application would run on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenVPN runs [fine under Windows](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1).  If running as a service, it'll need admin access, as it needs to change routing tables.

In terms of your dynamic IP address, you generally need to care only about one site.  The IP addresses for OpenVPN clients don't matter that much.  They just have to find the OpenVPN server.  You can get one static IP for the OpenVPN server, or you can use a service like dyndns and the clients would then be configured to look for myvpnserver.dyndns.org (or something along those lines).

Here's the [OpenVPN HOWTO](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).  Most likely, you'll install the OpenVPN server where you have the TFS box.

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN can work perfectly on linux and windows. You can use that to build a VPN.

For dynamic IP, you can use ddns like no-ip or dyndns so don't worry about the ISP change your IP.:)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend OpenVPN - it allows you to create routed or bridged network, depending on your needs, so I'm 90% sure it'll suit your needs.
Besides the OpenVPN HOWTO you might want to have a look at the examples: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/examples.html